# if statement in jQuery with JSON

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I want to make my border flash orange, but only when my statusByte_0 return a "1" via JSON from my plc.

```
<html>
    <body> 
        <script type="text/javascript">  
        var flashInterval = setInterval(function() 
        {
            $.getJSON("IOCounter.html", function(data) //Aufruf der IO-Liste
            {
              $('#statusByte_0').text(data.statusByte_0);
              if (data.statusByte_0)
          
              
              $('.LadepunktNummer').toggleClass('orange-border');
              };
          },);
        },1000);
        </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

I dont know how to continue with the if statement. The "'#statusByte_0'" is inside IOCounter and return Number 0 to 7. I want to toggleClass ('orange-border') when I get '#statusByte_0'= 1
Can you help me?

Comment: Should it not be ` if (data.statusByte_0 == 1)` if you want to do what you write in `I want to toggleClass ('orange-border') when I get '#statusByte_0'= 1 `

Comment: I dont even know the syntax, cause i'm noob with java and jquery. I will try. Thank you

Comment: @ Carsten Løvbo Andersen Thank you very much, it works. I wasnt that far away ;)